# Is DOM manipulation code queued or run synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

Why does the 1st snippet below behave differently from the 2nd one?

**In the first snippet, `box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';` runs with no delay and in the second snippet,`box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';` runs only after while loop completes. 
It is as if in the first case, it is queued to the event queue and in the second case, its run synchronously without queuing.**

First:

```
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  var start = new Date;
  while (new Date - start < 5000) {
    // wait 5 seconds...
  };
```

Second:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  var start = new Date;
  while (new Date - start < 5000) {
    // wait 5 seconds...
  };
}, 0);
```

Comment: Duplicate of many, many questions, use the search.

Comment: What is the point of this question?  DOM manipulation runs synchronously.  Repaints run asynchronously (when the browser feels like it).

Comment: How exactly does it behave differently?

Comment: Never use `while (new Date - start ...` in javascript!